# Navigation drawer header image

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I try to create a `Navigation Drawer`. I want to use my image in header of `Navigation Drawer`.

When I use my jpg image and open `Navigation Drawer`,  it opens very slowly and not working properly. I also want that my image should show in circle like in gmail App. I have put my jpeg image in `drawable` folder of 500kb size.

What can be done to solve this problem?

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp">

   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/headerImage"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/avina"/>

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerImage"
        android:id="@+id/headertext"
        android:text="Avinash"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `header_layout`. You can use this library for circular image.

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

Now your layout structure be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="304dp"
android:layout_height="172dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circularImageId"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/taplejung_nepal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginTextId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="@string/log_in"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can `inflate` this layout.  I assume you do have `NavigationView` in your drawer layout file.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationViewId);

View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
CircleImageView drawerHeaderImage = (CircleImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.circularImageId);
TextView user = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.loginTextId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Image size should be really small, like `120 x 120 px` is more than enough as a header image in `NavDrawer`.
And to make it circular follow below steps

Add below command in `build.gradle` dependencies

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
```

Build the `Application` and Add `CircularImageView` instead of `ImageView`

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/headerImage"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/avina"
        app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        app:civ_shadow_color="#8BC34A"/>
```

The above code blocks are copied and adapted [from `github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView` documentation](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView/blob/1640fa8dca11573fb16ec26ab00a6adb9a9a5e0e/README.md), by [Lopez Mikhael](https://github.com/lopspower).

Comment: It showing error E:\AndroidProject\Avinash\app\src\main\res\layout\header.xml
Error:(6) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Answer (score 0):

Use below library in your gradle;

'compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

then load your Imageview in xml;

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/your_picture"     />
```